# Change Other Users Crontab

Tags: linux, permissions, unix, cron

I've got a (deployment) script, that runs under my user 'me' and it should change the crontab of user 'ruby-server'. Am I right that the -u option (of crontab) doesn't help me much unless I use sudo or su? Is there a way, I can change an other users crontab without sudo or su. (I've got access to the entire system. )

*Why this problem you ask? Answer: If I deploy an application as 'me' and run it as 'ruby-server', obviously I want to write the crontab as 'me' but the commands should be in the crontab of the 'ruby-server'. Because if someone else deploys, we should change the same crontab of the same user*

[edit 1]

I've a group of users (the 'deployers') that have access to a server. I have one user ('ruby-server') that has via ssh and private key access to an other server to get some files. This copy is scripted via rsync and should be run every day. Now, I think, it would be cool if the 'deployers' could write to the 'ruby-server's crontab to specify / change the way the files are copied. Ideas?

Comment: And why not change the crontab of the system? That's where system crons belong to.

Comment: yes, but it's not a system cron, it's just a users cron. The application server is running with a specific 'ruby-server' user, this user has the cron. There are other application server users on this machine, which do not have access to the ruby-server

Comment: I still see no need for a user's cron. A system cron runs under the specified user. And if you want to configure something then make it outside of cron.

Comment: I see your point. Because the whole system was designed to use cron, I  will use cron. When I design the next system, I'll remember you statement and do it outside of cron.

Comment: This is **not** what I recommended. I only said that the configuration for the cron script must be outside of the cron command line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system has ACL you can grant access to the cronfile to the developers. If all the deployers are all part of a group named "deployers" you can modify the crontab file with the command displayed below, that would allow members of the group to modify it.

```
setfacl -m g:wheel:rx /var/spool/cron/ # Grant read access to the directory
setfacl -m g:deployers:rw /var/spool/cron/ruby-server
```

Keep in mind that /var/spool/cron/ruby-server must have the proper permissions: "chmod 0600 /var/spool/cron/ruby-server" will fix it if you see "BAD FILE MODE" messages in /var/log/cron

Also, the filesystem must have ACL enabled, running something like "tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/blah | grep -i acl" should be enough (substitute /dev/mapper/blah for the partition containing your /var/spool/cron directory)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way, I can change an other users crontab without sudo or su

AFAIK, there is no way. You need `sudo` permission to switch to another user first and creates cron jobs. Why you don't want to use `su` or `sudo` while you have full access to the system?

Comment: good point. actually I don't need full access to the system, I just have a group of people that deploys an application to the same folder / user 'ruby-server' and this 'ruby-server' user has the right to access an  other folder on a other server where some import files are.